# MySQL query from excel without ODBC

Tags: excel, vba, mysql-connector

Is possible to get connection to mysql server from excel macro, without downloading any ODBC connector? I have found solutions only with this connector. Problem is, that I have to send excel workbook to some people which they don't have this connector in their computer, and it will be a little problem to set it for them.

I need to make only one INSERT query.

Comment: You can't connect to mysql without using any external libraries, which the other users may not have either. You have to ask them to install something anyway. MyODBC has a really user friendly installer and using it from VBA is a lot simpler than other solutions.

Comment: FWIW ADODB is usually included by default in most Windows installations. `Microsoft.ActiveX.DataObjects` is the name of the library in Tools/References. That's newer than ODBC and I'd think mysql would support it...

Comment: @CindyMeister you still need to install myodbc to be able to connect to mysql...